# Specifying optional parameters when calling JavaScript functions in Dart

Tags: dart

I'm calling the function `window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` from Dart code. The final parameter to this function is optional. In JavaScript I would set the optional parameters as follows:

```js
var wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error,
  {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:30000, timeout:27000});
```

What would the equivalent be in Dart code? I've tried the following but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```dart
window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error,
 {'enableHighAccuracy':true, 'maximumAge':30000, 'timeout':27000});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using this method: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_html/Geolocation.html#watchPosition

```dart
int watchPosition(PositionCallback successCallback, [PositionErrorCallback errorCallback, Object options])
```

I do not have Dark SDK on this machine, but to me it looks completely fine. If the JavaScript equivalent code is just an object, then passing a Dart Map just like what you have done should be working. Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully passing a Map works, please try and let us know.

Even if it does work, this is a bad Dart API. The options really should be optional parameters, not properties of an options object. I filed a bug here: http://dartbug.com/6280